# Java8 and spring boot parsing XML namespace declarations

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, soap

I am getting a soap request where the `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope` is followed by a carriage return and line feed and then `xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

So it looks like

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

But my parser errors out with

`ERROR:  'Element type "SOAP-ENV:Envelopexmlns" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Is this a parser problem or is this invalid XML?

Comment: Looks invalid to me... Is that the whole thing?

Comment: This is the "whole" part.  

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
...`

Comment: Isn't the cr/lf considered whitespace?

Comment: Ah, never mind. From your post it looked truncated.